# How do I search for certain sections of a file and then extract only relevant information within that section?

Tags: shell, shell-script, awk, scripting, grep

I have a text file that is a server report which has about 1000 lines of information in it. I'm trying to write a script that can search the report for only certain pieces of information I'm looking for.

For example:

> Server 1 Health Check
>
> Date - Count of errors
>
> ---
>
> **06/25/15** : **14**
>
> **6/24/15** :  **21**
>
> **6/23/15** :  **17**
>
> **6/24/15** :  **33**
>
> Server 2 Health Check
>
> Date   -   Count of errors
>
> ---
>
> **06/25/15** : **4**
>
> **6/24/15** :  **13**
>
> **6/23/15** :  **21**
>
> **6/24/15** :  **33**
>
> Errors caused by X
>
> ---
>
> Server 1:
>
> **32**
>
> Server 2:
>
> **24**

The three sections are

- "Server Health Check 1",
- "Server Health Check 2", and
- "Errors caused by x."

The data from each section that I need extracted is in bold.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?
I know that I can use `grep` but I can't use `grep` with the `-A`, `-B`, and `-C` flags.

Comment: Please read the [formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have GNU tools you can do:

```
for match in \
    Server\ Health\ Check\ 1
    Server\ Health\ Check\ 2
    Errors\ caused\ by\ X
do  grep -Fxm1 "$match"
    case $match in 
    (S*) sed -nEu '/^[0-9/:]+/!q;p';;
    (*)  sed -u '4q;3d;1d';;
esac;done <file
```

The assumption here is that there is *some* intervening data between the sections you're interested in *(because otherwise: `cat`)*.

Without GNU tools:

```
grep -nxE 'Server Health Check [12]|Errors caused by X' <file |
sed 's|\([^:]*\):S.*|\1,/\n.*[^0-9/:]/{\1!P?}?|
     s|\([^:]*\):E.*|\1{N;s/.*\\n//p;N;s///p?}?|
     y/?/\n/' | sed -e1!N -f- -eD ./file
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a **sed** script with gotos (shock, horror). This could be simplified if you
describe your data more precisely.

```
sed -n '
:start
  /Server .* Health Check/{
      n
      /Date - Count/n
   :loop1
      / : /{p; n; b loop1
      }
      b start
  }
  /Errors caused by/{
      n
   :loop2
      /Server/n
      /^[0-9]/{p; n; b loop2
      }
      b start
  }
'
```

The script recognises the first style of header, and enters the {} part. It
reads the next line (n) and if it is the Date header, reads another line.
If the line matches the " : " style line (/ : /) it enters the {} part
which prints the line (p), reads the next line (n), and branches (b) to label loop1.
When no more lines match it branches to label start.

The same thing happens when the 2nd style of header is seen.

Comment: Only thing, though: `/ : /` seems a might sparse. I dunno. I like it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought something like `/\/.*\/.* : [0-9]/` was too hard to read for a simple answer. The question is a little vague to bother to be too specific.

Answer (score 0):

Use a full scripting language, e.g. Perl, Python or Ruby according to what you are most familiar with. If none, probably learning Python will give you most bang for buck. Many Linux distributions use Python for non-performance critical system tools and tasks, knowing how to read those will pay off some day.

Being able to search, dissect lines and scrape information out, and organize results in flexible, capable data structures will save work in this case, and in the many similar ones to follow.